# How can I convert the python class str to dictionary in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, json, eel

I have a data in python that is in this format

```
 d1 = ["id":"hajdgrwe2123", "name":"john law", "age":"95"]
```

Python has it as data type " class 'str' ".

I am sending the data from python to javascript using eel so I want to convert the data to dictionary in javascript so that I can make the call below

d1["id"] # result should be hajdgrwe2123

I tried converting to json in javascript but it did not work. How can I convert the python class str to dictionary in javascript?

Comment: `d1 = {"id":"hajdgrwe2123", "name":"john law", "age":"95"}` is the correct format. Doesn't seem like a JS question to me, more like a python + JSON one.

Answer (score 1):

When sending from Python to JS, you need to encode the data as JSON (using `json.dumps()` for example).

Then, you can parse it to a JS object using:

```
const d1 = JSON.parse(json_data);
```

You can access it's properties using:

```
d1['id'] // prints: hajdgrwe2123
```

or:

```
d1.id // prints: hajdgrwe2123
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [json.dumps()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) function to convert a Python object to a JSON object string:

```py
import json

d1 = {"id":"hajdgrwe2123", "name":"john law", "age":"95"}

json_str = json.dumps(d1)

# json_str = '{"id": "hajdgrwe2123", "name": "john law", "age": "95"}'
# Do something with json_str to pass it to the Javascript process
```

The JSON object can then be used as suggested by domenikk https://stackoverflow.com/a/64424921/14349691.